# When are LOCAL static variables initialized

Tags: c

I keep on seeing the same sentence that static variables are initialized only once, and I also saw a sentence stating that "when the block is entered for the first time".

Are local static variables initialized like other global variables - at the start of program execution? Or do local static variables differ from normal globals, and only get initialized once their function/block is called/reached?

Comment: Note that static initialisation in C++ is very different from static initialisation in C. If you're not careful to check which language is being discussed, you can get very confused. I suspect that the sentence you "also saw" was not about C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C17 6.2.4 (3)

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier `_Thread_local`, and either
> with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier `static`, has static storage duration.
> Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, **prior
> to program startup.**

However, remember the *as-if rule*.  An implementation *could* wait to initialize the variable until the first call to the function, as a conforming program has no way to access its value before then, and so would not be able to tell the difference.

If you have an implementation with extensions or implementation-defined behavior that do provide a way to access the variable before the first call to the function, then such an implementation ought to document whether you would see the initialized value in such a case.  In most cases I would expect the answer to be "yes".

The most common implementation I'm familiar with is to load the initial value from the executable, or to place it in a `bss` section that is zeroed at startup, just as is done for global or file-scope `static` variables.

Comment: A concrete example is that static objects defined in functions in a dynamically loaded library are not initialized until the library is loaded. The program may start and run for a while (or even finish) without using the library. When it does use the library, the library’s static objects will be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Although implementation dependent, static variables - any scope - are initialized as the executable is loaded.